# Break in square root line

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, pdf

I'm having a problem where the line that runs the top length of my square root sign is discontinuous.

```
\begin{equation}
    N_t(\text{V})=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n}N_i^2}
\end{equation}
```

Yields this...[image: Sad broken line]

Any ideas what's causing that broken line on the top of my root symbol??

Comment: The left part is a character (or characters) from the font, the top part is a rule drawn by TeX, these are specified to be the same width but font hinting and pixel rounding and bad luck can mean that the join shows at some zoom levels.

Comment: So, am I just out of luck?

Comment: @user2865011 In what sense? You are “out of luck”, but does it matter? As David pointed: “*the join **shows** at some zoom levels*”.

Comment: Using the old    \surd symbol would make the join less obvious.

Comment: @JohnKormylo why?

Comment: @ David Carlisle - The join would occur at a corner rather than along a straight stretch.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to overlay a thicker line over the two joined lines.

[image: overlay]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\newlength{\myline}
\newlength{\myoffset}
\newcommand{\mysqrt}[1]%
{\setlength{\myline}{.1ex}%
\addtolength{\myline}{.06pt}%
\setlength{\myoffset}{.9em}
\addtolength{\myoffset}{-2pt}
\savebox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle\sqrt{#1}$}%
\settoheight{\myheight}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
\addtolength{\myheight}{-.2ex}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
\addtolength{\mywidth}{-\myoffset}%
 \rlap{\usebox{\mybox}}\hspace{\myoffset}{\raisebox{\myheight}{\rule{\mywidth}{\myline}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\begin{equation*}
\mysqrt{\sum_{k=0}^\infty} \quad {\huge\mysqrt{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}} \quad {\tiny\mysqrt{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This kind of works, but now I get thin->thick line step, for a change.

Comment: So much work for a line!