# How do I de-ascii-artify polynomial divison with polynom?

Tags: polynom

The following code shows a polynomial long division:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
    \polylongdiv[style=A]{6x^3-2x^2+x+3}{x^2-x+1}
\end{document}
```

The output of the above code is (without the red highlight):

[image]

I have studied the package documentation for polynom without finding a way to de-ascii-artify the highlighted part. My desired output would be something along the lines of:

[image]

How can I modify the behaviour of polynom to produce the desired output?

Comment: email the package author?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153295/long-division-of-polynomials-in-lyx/153413?s=1|3.1560#153413

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I prefer not having to manually meddle with the spacing (\hphantom{...} etc), but yes, it does work.

Comment: In a somewhat related problem (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168806/break-in-square-root-line/168943?s=1|3.8989#168943) I tried to develop font independent offsets.  It wasn't perfect and involved some odd calculations, but was able to fit a wide range of sizes.