# Thinner square root line than expected

Tags: luatex, fontspec, bold, unicode-math, opentype

I am using Fira font in my document, text and math. The problem is that the math font is way too thin, so I ended up using `FakeBold` option from `fontspec`. Everything is OK until the square roots. As you can see they are being showed like this:
[image]

I have been looking for the `\sqrt` definition on LaTeX source and similar, but I found no solution.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont[
  BoldFont={Fira Sans Bold},
  ItalicFont={Fira Sans Medium Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Bold Italic}
]{Fira Sans Medium}
\setmathfont[FakeBold=2.5]{FiraMath-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
\[
\omega_1\sqrt{\frac{\left(I_1-I_3\right)\left(I_1-I_2\right)}{I_2I_3}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168806/break-in-square-root-line/168943?r=SearchResults&s=1|57.3597#168943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont[
  BoldFont={Fira Sans Bold},
  ItalicFont={Fira Sans Medium Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Bold Italic}
]{Fira Sans Medium}
\setmathfont[FakeBold=2.5]{FiraMath-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{$x$} % force math initialisation

\Umathradicalrule\displaystyle=1.4pt


\[
\omega_1\sqrt{\frac{\left(I_1-I_3\right)\left(I_1-I_2\right)}{I_2I_3}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that is a workaround. Thanks. Could you provide some references so I can also learn?

Comment: @RafaJuradoAriza This can be found in the LuaTeX manual (`texdoc luatex`), section 7.4 "Math parameter settings".

Comment: @MarcelKrüger so yeah that is... and why does someone need to initialise math?

Comment: you could raise that at the unicode-math github, unicode-math probably wasn't expecting you to fake bold the main math font so (a) doesn't scale up the font parameters to match (although I did that by eye, simply multiplying the original value by 2.5 looked too much)  and (b) doesn't give any interface to dropping in your own settings in a sensible place (unless @MarcelKrüger says I missed somewhere)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle will do