# Lines of the square root don't match

Tags: sqrt

the line of the square root don't match.

```
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \mathlarger{\sum}_{n=1}^{N} \left( x_{n}-  \mu  \right) ^{2}}
```

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: the left part is a character and the top part is a rule so the details depend on the font (you have given no information) and the way your pdf viewer (you have not said which) snaps rules and characters to pixel boundaries.

Comment: Please check if zooming in fixes the issue -- have seen that problen over the years. Then, it is a problem with the pdf viewer which can be resolved by switching pdf viewers until the problem is resolved in the original viewer. Futhermore,  while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. In this case it would also be helpful to mention the pdf viewer.

Comment: David and Peter already told you why this happens. In ConTeXt it is possible to use glyphs instead of rules for the bar, and then this problem [usually goes away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STL5P.png).

Comment: What you've encountered is a sceen resolution artefact. I won't show up in print.

Comment: Off-topic: Do try to ween yourself off an excessive reliance on `\left` and `\right`. For the equation at hand, the `\left` and `\right` directives do nothing useful, but do create needless code clutter.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168806/break-in-square-root-line