How to reduce the width of the top horizontal line in the `\sqrt` command?
I would like to ask how to reduce the width of the top horizontal line in the \sqrt command. I noticed that the top horizontal line of the square root symbol differs in width between the STIX font and the default CM font. When I replaced the square root symbol in the stix-mathex.pfb font with the one from cmex10.pfb, the result showed a noticeable discrepancy in line thickness.
I also tried modifying the default line thickness in the stix-mathex.tfm file to match that of cmex10.tfm, but this adjustment only improved the line thickness for the \overline and \frac commands, leaving the \sqrt command unaffected. How can I achieve the desired result?
The MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%\setbox0=\hbox{$$}
%\fontdimen8\textfont3=0.5pt 

\begin{document}

\[ \sqrt{\sum_{\sum_1^2}^{\gamma}}\]

\end{document}



the width is set by the font (it is the height of the sqrtsign, all the rest of the symbol is in the depth) so you should not get the output you show, please show the input you used.

Hello, my MWE is as follows:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%\setbox0=\hbox{$$}
%\fontdimen8\textfont3=0.5pt 

\begin{document}

\[ \sqrt{\sum_{\sum_1^2}^{\gamma}}\]

\end{document}

As I mentioned in the title, I replaced the square root symbol by modifying the stix-mathex.pfb file, so I didn’t replace the symbol within the MWE.tex file itself.

as you see you need to put code blocks in the question they do not work in comments. As I say you need to make the height of the character  be the thickness of the top rule, but modifying a pfb font directly (and making the tfm still match) is not really on topic (and I wouldn't know how to do it)

why modify the pfb this seems a tricky thing to get right and makes your document completely non-portable, you could simply use the square root from cmex if that's what you want.

Because I want to replicate the font used in the formulas of Physical Review Letters (PRL), I checked its fonts using pdffonts but didn’t get specific results. Through comparison, I found that the formula font used in PRL is essentially STIX (with the math italic being partially replaced from the text italic?). The symbols, however, are from the CM font. As a result, I had to modify the PFB file to achieve the desired outcome.

It is very unlikley they are changing the font, just simply specifying that certain characters come from stix and others come from computer modern,

Hey, since the results I obtained using the pdffonts command are as follows: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qmNnWYH2mj/
It seems like the font names here are custom-defined? (Please forgive my limited understanding of font encoding.) Therefore, I attempted to modify the PFB font file.

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168806/break-in-square-root-line

I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted when I compile your code on my system (MacOS, MacTeX2024 with all updates applied, Stix package version 2018/04/17 v1.1.3).

Today, we have Unicode fonts (for example STIXMath-Regular.otf) so we are using 8bit fonts only if we want to do an exploration of computers history. I recommend: use only Unicode fonts today, forget about the existence of 8bit fonts. On the other hand, if you want to explore the TeX and computer history, you can dive to ancient pfb and tfm formats of fonts. Your mistake is that you changed glyph in pfb but didn't change relevant metric in the tfm. The rule width is given by the height of the character saved in the tfm file. The ancient tftopl and pltotf programs enables you to edit tfm files.

the pdffonts output looks like just standard fonts, the BEJJDN.. prefix are just a prefix added while font subsetting, there is no need to modify any fonts

@Mico the OP has modified the font using a font editor so it no longer matches its font metrics, which is the cause of the issue.

@wipet My PL file is as follows. Could you please tell me which parameter I should modify? (I added the following content in the stix-mathex.tfm file:
(DEFAULTRULETHICKNESS R 0.039999)
(BIGOPSPACING1 R 0.111112)
(BIGOPSPACING2 R 0.166667)
(BIGOPSPACING3 R 0.2)
(BIGOPSPACING4 R 0.6)
(BIGOPSPACING5 R 0.1)
```)

the pl file is locate at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p4CZVMPfwz/

@Mico Hey, actually, since I modified the square root symbol in the stix-mathex.pfb file, you won't be able to get the result shown in my screenshot unless you also make the corresponding replacement.

@wipet In fact, I am more interested in 8-bit Type 1 fonts. I want to try creating a math font from scratch, but I am stuck with the encoding files and TFM files. I know that FontForge can generate the necessary files for LaTeX, but when I use the TFM file generated by FontForge (e.g., stix-mathex-my.tfm), I get the following result: ! Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. Do you have any relevant references for creating Type 1 math fonts?

This is a consequence of the resource saving strategies used by Knuth.
There is no fontdimen that deal with the thickness of the vinculum, because the radical will need to be vertically adjusted anyway, so Knuth saved some memory space by making the radical character to mostly hang below the baseline; the character's height is what's used for the thickness of the vinculum.
Let's do some comparison. For Computer Modern, the radical is at slot 0x70 in either the symbol font (family 2) or the large symbols font (family 3).
We can easily ask TeX to show the heights:
\showthe\fontcharht\textfont2"70
\showthe\fontcharht\textfont3"70
\bye

(compile with pdftex) to get, in both cases, 0.39998pt (which is the same as 0.4pt).
For STIX Two it's a bit more complicated. In stix2.sty we find
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}  {LS2}{stix2ex}   {m} {n}
[...]
\stix@MathRadical{\sqrtsign}    {largesymbols}{"F9}{largesymbols}{"74}

Let's find what's in LS2stix2ex.fd:
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2ex}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathex}{}

so we can repeat the test above by selecting the TFM file
\font\test=stix2-mathex

\showthe\fontcharht\test"F9
\showthe\fontcharht\test"74

\bye

to get, in both cases, 0.68pt.
Replacing the characters in stix-mathex.pfb with the characters in cmsy10.pfb and cmex10.pfb (you need both and there are several radicals in cmex10) isn't enough: you also need to modify the TFM file to have a height of 0.4pt instead of 0.68pt (and to ensure that the position of the glyph is correct).
You can see that the character is from cmex10.pfb, but the vinculum has the thickness advertised in the TFM file that you haven't changed.

\font\test=stix2-mathex

CM

\vrule height 0.05pt depth0.05pt width 15pt \kern-15pt
{\tenex\char"70}

\bigskip

STIX Two

\vrule height 0.05pt depth0.05pt width 15pt \kern-15pt
{\test\char"74}

\bye

The hairlines show the baseline:

If we do tftopl cmex10, we see the series of the large radicals starting from octal 160 (hexadecimal 70)
(CHARACTER O 160
   (CHARWD R 1.000003)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 1.160013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 161)
   )
(CHARACTER O 161
   (CHARWD R 1.000003)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 1.760019)
   (NEXTLARGER O 162)
   )
(CHARACTER O 162
   (CHARWD R 1.000003)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 2.360025)
   (NEXTLARGER O 163)
   )
(CHARACTER O 163
   (CHARWD R 1.000003)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
   (NEXTLARGER O 164)
   )
(CHARACTER O 164
   (CHARWD R 1.055559)
   (CHARDP R 1.800018)
   (VARCHAR
      (TOP O 166)
      (BOT O 164)
      (REP O 165)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 165
   (CHARWD R 1.055559)
   (CHARDP R 0.600006)
   )
(CHARACTER O 166
   (CHARWD R 1.055559)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 0.560007)
   )

where you see that all of them are assigned a height of 0.4pt (conversion from scaled point may differ in the last digit for TeX or TFtoPL). With stix2-mathex we need to start from character t (ASCII hex "74)
(CHARACTER C t
   (CHARWD R 1.041)
   (CHARHT R 0.068)
   (CHARDP R 1.811)
   (NEXTLARGER C u)
   )
(CHARACTER C u
   (CHARWD R 1.177)
   (CHARHT R 0.068)
   (CHARDP R 2.302)
   (NEXTLARGER C v)
   )
(CHARACTER C v
   (CHARWD R 1.17)
   (CHARHT R 0.068)
   (CHARDP R 2.823)
   (NEXTLARGER C w)
   )
(CHARACTER C w
   (CHARWD R 1.212)
   (CHARHT R 0.068)
   (CHARDP R 1.811)
   (NEXTLARGER C y)
   )
(CHARACTER C x
   (CHARWD R 1.212)
   (CHARHT R 0.45)
   )
(CHARACTER C y
   (CHARWD R 1.212)
   (CHARHT R 0.068)
   (CHARDP R 0.473)
   (VARCHAR
      (TOP C y)
      (BOT C w)
      (REP C x)
      )
   )

where you see the 0.68pt height.

Well, but this brings up another issue. When I convert the stix-mathex.tfm file to a PL file, the result is as follows: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p4CZVMPfwz/. Which parameter should I adjust? It is worth noting that I replaced the last part of the FONTDIMEN section at the beginning of the file with the content from cmex10.tfm:
(DEFAULTRULETHICKNESS R 0.039999)
(BIGOPSPACING1 R 0.111112)
(BIGOPSPACING2 R 0.166667)
(BIGOPSPACING3 R 0.2)
(BIGOPSPACING4 R 0.6)
(BIGOPSPACING5 R 0.1)


@tsiayi It's not among the font dimensions. You need to look at the characters.

Thank you for your guidance, this issue has been resolved!

@tsiayi I suggest making a virtual font instead of replacing characters in the pfb file and changing the TFM file. Do texdoc vptovf for information and peruse the TUGboat index.

OKey! Thank you for your patient guidance.

Dear egreg, could you please provide me with more detailed resources on how to hack and use virtual fonts? I tried searching on Google, but I found very little relevant information.

@tsiayi https://duckduckgo.com/?sites=tug.org%2FTUGboat%2F&q=virtual+font&ia=web
